# sql server Divide by zero error

Tags: sql-server

Any way I have a query in the following form

```
select 
(select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) / ((select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) + 0.000001) 
from sometable
```

Im dividing the result of a count by the result of a count, so nulls are not an issue.

When I run this I get a "Divide by zero error encountered.". Notice the +0.000001 in the divisor.

If I insert the enumerator (?) and divisor in a new table and then do the same calc it works as expected.

```
select 
(select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) a/ ((select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) + 0.000001) b
into testtable
from sometable
```

select a/b from testtable

this returns the expected results with no errors.

If I run

```
select * from testtable where b = 0
i get 0 records as expected.
```

I really losing it here, this is a 5 minute job that has turn into a 5 hour mess.

I've also tried

```
select *
((select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) + 0.000001) divisor
from sometable
where divisor = 0
```

This returns no records.

Comment: Well, I tried `select (select count(*) from sometable where 1=2)/(
select (select count(*) from sometable where 1=2) + 0.000001)` and didn't get an error. So, to be honest, I've got no clue as to what's going on... But you might try my query just to look if that's an issue?

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I couldn't reproduce your problem either but this should work regardless.

```
WITH Divisor AS (select count(*)*1.0 BotCnt from sys.procedures),
    Dividend AS (select count(*)*1.0 TopCnt from sys.tables )
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN BotCnt = 0 THEN 0 ELSE TopCnt/BotCnt END,
    *
FROM sys.objects
CROSS JOIN Divisor
CROSS JOIN Dividend
```

Note the `*1.0`.  That is to convert the count to a decimal.  You could use an explicit conversion just as easily.  The CROSS JOINs only works because the two CTEs are single row.  Otherwise use an INNER JOIN with an ON clause.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I could come to replicating your scenario quickly, and it works fine; returns 0.0000000:

```
with sometable as (
  select * from ( values 
    (0)
  ) sometable(value)
)
select 
  (select count(*) from sometable where value <> 0 )
/ 
( (select count(*) from sometable where value <> 0 ) + 0.000001 ) 
from sometable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `NULLIF` on your divisor

```
select 
(select count(*) from sometable where somecritiea) / NULLIF((select count(*) from sometable     where somecritiea) + 0.000001), 0) from sometable
```

This will return `NULL` instead of divide by 0 whenever denominator is 0. If you dont want `NULL` but some other default answer(eg 9), use `ISNULL` on whole query to convert it back to 0.